# Effects of Ionizing a Radioactive Isotope

Tags: ions, atoms, radioactivity

If you took your favorite radioactive isotope and ionized it using a strong electric field (or any other ionization method), thereby stripping it of an electron, what would happen when it decayed? For simplicity, assume this process takes place in a vacuum.

Would the resulting material also be ionized? (Main Question)

If the isotope decayed via beta decay, is there any chance the produced electron could take the place of the stripped electron?

Comment: An intriguing question, especially as (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay#Types_of_decay) hints that there is more than just $\alpha, \beta^+, \beta^-$-decay.  Not only in terms of "what does it mean for a single, isolated atom", but even for radiopharmaceutical compounds like 18F-FDG (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fludeoxyglucose_(18F)), where the $\ce{^{18}F}$ turns into $\ce{^{18}O}$ ...

Comment: I don't really think so. Energy levels in the nucleus are really large compared to electronic energy levels. A beta electron would have a lot of energy, it would overcome all the electronic energy states and simply fly away.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal - That is what I was thinking as well. If I'm not mistaken, the electrons produced through beta decay move at a significant fraction of the speed of light. Is that correct?

Do you have any thoughts on the first question, though? Would the resulting material also be ionized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no effect. Imagine you are demolishing a building with high explosives; does it matter whether the small window on the third floor was open or closed prior to the explosion? No, it doesn't. The building will go crashing down all the same.

I believe this is a correct metaphor of the relation between chemistry and radioactivity. Of course the product will be ionized. Quite probably, it will be *multiply* ionized via [Auger events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auger_effect), and also will certainly ionize quite a few other atoms around. Whether it was ionized *before* is about as unimportant as that small window on the third floor.